# Implementation of REP-tree and M5P-tree algorithms in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, data-science

I am working on a prediction problem with decision tree ( REP-Tree and M5P-Tree ) and I'm wondering if there is an existing implementation of those algorithms in python ?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that scikit-learn team is working on it as of Nov 2020. See [discussion](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13106)

In the meanwhile, people have shared the code you may use [here](https://github.com/ankonzoid/LearningX/tree/master/advanced_ML/model_tree) and [here](https://medium.com/convoy-tech/the-best-of-both-worlds-linear-model-trees-7c9ce139767d)